# C# httpclient with Task<string> that return content

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await, dotnet-httpclient

I've the following function but can't debug it because response never come. Service on the other side is working. Any help will be preciated, I can't deduce how must be do it with other answers in SO

```
    public async Task<string> PostObjectToWebServiceAsJSON(object objectToPost, string validatorName, string method)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("myuri" + "/" + method);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            // HTTP POST
            var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("", objectToPost);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }
            else
            {
                string errplugin = "Error";

                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

This is how I call it:

```
    public PaymentResponseInternal Post(some stuff here)
    {
        Task<string> retornoPluginAsync = PostObjectToWebServiceAsJSON(some stuff here);

        retornoPluginAsync.Wait();
        string result = retornoPluginAsync.Result;

        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PaymentResponseInternal>(result);
    }
```

Comment: When you say "response never come", what do you mean? Is it hanging? How are you calling this function? It's likely a deadlock.

Comment: Yes, it goes to the service, the service response but doesn't do anymore after. Let me update the question with how I call it

Comment: So yeah, it's a deadlock because you are calling `retornoPluginAsync.Result`. You need to `await` that call. See here: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html

Comment: It sounds like `public PaymentResponseInternal Post(some stuff here)` should be `public async Task<PaymentResponseInternal> Post(some stuff here)` and should internally make use of `await`.

Comment: I miss an "await" in my question, sorry. I update it! but let me see what are you writing here. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry but how I transform Task<PaymentResponseInternal> to PaymentResponseInternal then?

Comment: You await that function too. async code is like a virus, once you start, it will slowly consume your whole project (which is a good thing)

Comment: lol!!! but I can't do that because  I come from other call that can't wait :(

Comment: Then look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9343594/how-to-call-asynchronous-method-from-synchronous-method-in-c), unfortunately, only you will be able to tell which is the most suitable method to solve your issue.

Comment: @Sven that is the weird scenario that motivates this question, i get the data posted in the other service, and the service sends a response, but nothing happens :S

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you should make `PaymentResponseInternal` an `async` method that returns a `Task<PaymentResponseInternal>` and await it.

You shouldn’t mix synchronous and asynchronous code. One of the reasons for this is that you might deadlock as you have discovered here. Please refer to @Stephen Cleary's article on the subject for more information: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx

If you can't make your `Post` method `async` for some reason, you could try not to capture the context in the `PostObjectToWebServiceAsJSON` method by calling `ConfigureAwait(false)` after each `await`:

```
public async Task<string> PostObjectToWebServiceAsJSON(object objectToPost, string validatorName, string method)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("myuri" + "/" + method);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("", objectToPost).ConfigureAwait(false);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Please refer to @Stephen Cleary's blog post for information about this: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html

Answer (score 1):

With your update to the question, you're running into a deadlock situation when you call `PostObjectToWebServiceAsJSON` synchronously. You should add a call to `retornoPluginAsync.ConfigureAwait(false);` before you `Wait()` for it. `ConfigureAwait(false)` configures the `Task` to not require the original call context and should, in your case, solve the deadlock.

```
    public PaymentResponseInternal Post(some stuff here)
    {
        Task<string> retornoPluginAsync = PostObjectToWebServiceAsJSON(some stuff here);
        retornoPluginAsync.ConfigureAwait(false); // Add this
        retornoPluginAsync.Wait();
        string result = retornoPluginAsync.Result;

        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PaymentResponseInternal>(result);
    }
```

Comment: I do it that, and compiles but don't return anything.

Comment: Actually I miss the await in the question

Comment: Looks like the code in the question is a moving target which is invalidating responses being posted...

Comment: This answer was clearly never going to work anyway as OP definitely had code that compiled.

Comment: yep, sorry David, my mistake, I remove await trying something but forget to write it again

Comment: @Georg Just remove the whole first part of your answer, it's not relevant or useful at all.

Comment: @DavidG, I've removed the now obsolete part.

Comment: I tried, but same result :( I added that line and now at least I get the breakpoint on the     retornoPluginAsync.Wait(); but never comes to if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) and nothing happens. At the service side, the data is coming and working fine